# How to get VBS to read from text file?

Tags: vbscript, wmi, uninstallation, wmi-query

I am looking to turn a single computer script into a mass use script.  What it does as it stands is allow me to select which parts of Windows Essentials to uninstall by pulling from a text file.  However, as it sits, it just prompts for a SINGLE computer name...I want it to pull from a separate text file that I have created Computer_Names.txt, and run the uninstall on all computers in that list.  I just can't seem to get it correct.

```
Const ForReading = 1
strComputer = InputBox("Enter the Computer Name:- ") 

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile ("C:\Windows_Live_Components.txt", ForReading)
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")


StrOutput = "Uninstalled the following Software:- "
Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
strNextLine = objTextFile.Readline
arrSoftwareList = Split(strNextLine , ",")
Set colSoftware = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_Product Where Name = " & Chr(34) & arrSoftwareList(0) & Chr(34) )
For Each objSoftware in colSoftware
    objSoftware.Uninstall()
    strOutput = stroutput & vbCrLf & objsoftware.Name
Next
Loop
WScript.Echo strOutput
```

Content of the Computer_Names.txt file would just be something like this. Each computer on a separate line of text.

```
LAPD2712
LAPD2812
```

All our computer names are 4 upper-case letters, 4 numbers.

Comment: Please post contents of text file.

Comment: Just edited main post to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
Dim objFSO, objComponentsTextFile, objComputersTextFile, objWMIService, strComputer, StrOutput
Dim computerArray(), softwareArray, x
x = 0
Redim computerArray(x)


Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objComponentsTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile ("C:\Windows_Live_Components.txt", 1)
Set objComputersTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile ("C:\Computers.txt", 1)

Do Until objComputersTextFile.AtEndOfStream
    computerArray(x) = objComputersTextFile.ReadLine
    x = x + 1
    Redim Preserve computerArray(x)
Loop

x = 0

softwareArray = Split(objComponentsTextFile.ReadLine, ",")

For Each computer in computerArray
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & computer & "\root\cimv2")
    StrOutput = "Uninstalled the following Software:- "
    For Each software in softwareArray
        Set colSoftware = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_Product Where Name = " & Chr(34) & software & Chr(34) )
        objSoftware.Uninstall()
        strOutput = strOutput & vbCrLf & objsoftware.Name 
    Next
    WScript.Echo strOutput
Next
```

This loads the data from your text files into arrays then loops on the arrays. I think you previously had an issue with a text stream getting at the `AtTheEndOfStream` and not going back and forth, which would explain why it'd process only the first computer.

Comment: Right, I wanted to get rid of the Input Box.  However I can't seem to get it to take the first line in Computer_Names, run it through the uninstall, then take the next line, run it...until the end.

Comment: Getting a line 5, char 1.  Invalid procedure call or argument.  If it is too troublesome, don't worry about it, and I'll likely just end up doing this in a more manual way than I wish, as my own coding skills are pretty rudimentary.

Comment: Did not have the ForReading constant defined in my snipped. Changed for 1 instead. Should work. I can't totally reproduce it here so I have no software I want to install ATM.

Comment: Almost there it appears.  It doesn't throw errors, however it only works on the first computer on the list.  It does pop the echo up at the end correctly, saying it uninstalled programs, I hit okay, it pops a 2nd one up, and says it uninstalled nothing.

I thought maybe it was a WMI issue on the 2nd target computer, but I swapped them around in Computers_List.txt and it worked on the first one again.

Comment: Are you patient enough ? Look at the wscript.exe process and see what it does. Apparently, querying Product is very slow http://sdmsoftware.com/group-policy-blog/wmi/why-win32_product-is-bad-news/

Comment: Heading home for the day anywho.  Thank you very much.  My guess is this, since it will return a blank if no software was uninstalled.  It isn't set to check the next line in Computers_List.  It properly uninstalls on the first computer, then tries to uninstall the same stuff on the first computer, resulting in a blank output.